# Observations with very high or very low residuals in regression

Tags: regression, residuals

If a regression model is applied and there exist residuals that is very high or very low (meaning outliers compared to the others), is it good practice to get rid of those observations and then do the regression again, particularly if you have a very big sample of data?

Comment: There are many, many posts on questions such as you are asking. In this case, search for posts on outliers.

Answer (score 2):

It's well-known that outliers can shift the slopes of a linear regression model. Intuitively it's similar to the reasons the mean is more sensitive to outliers than the median. So it's a good idea to run regression diagnostics (see John Fox's `car` package in R for some great utilities). Another option would be to model the median (or some other summary measure of the outcome) rather the mean (as we typically use in regression models). The `quantreg` function in the `rq` package can fit regression models with the median or some other quantile.

Comment: High leverage values do not necessarily have a large residual, nor are large residuals necessarily indicative of high leverage.